# Game of guessing or is it!

Tags: regression, probability, predictive-models, probability-inequalities, mode

I am trying to learn coding and want to create a simple game. The idea is that there are 20 different animals, and you have 5 rooms, each round 5 out of the 20 animals hide in the room, where behind the door of each room there is one unknown animal. The player who guess all the animals wins. Is there a statistical model to predict animals in the rooms?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, yes, is there a statistical model to predict animals in the rooms?

Comment: No, if the animals are chosen at random there is no way to predict which animal is behind which door, or at least you cannot do any better than randomly guessing yourself.

Comment: How come? We know the number of rooms, the total variables and it's just down to random choices probability, right?

Comment: But that's the point of randomness... it's random, i.e. it cannot be predicted, otherwise it wouldn't be random. Can you predict the outcome of a coin flip? Or a throw of a die?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [lottery mathematics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics). The number of possible combinations of animals behind the door is $20 \times 19 \times 17 \times 16 \times 15 = \frac{20!}{14!} = 1860480$. So the probability to guess correctly is a bit higher than one in two million.

---

When the problem is about the player with the most correct guesses who wins (not just the problem of getting all correct):

If the guessing is done in steps, such that after opening one door the guess for the next door is being made (with information about the previously opened doors), then the number of correct guesses is [Poison Binomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) distributed.